# (scheme) Cons a number to the front of sublists?

Tags: scheme

I have a function that finds the distance of 2 coordinates and puts it in the front of the corresponding sublist. Right now, it only finds the distance of the first coordinates. I think something is wrong with the recursion since it seems to not be moving on to the other coordinates.

Here's what should be happening:

```
~(storedist distance '(1 7) '((d (1 8)) (d (2 9))))
((1 (d (1 8))) (2 (d (2 9))))
```

Here's what's happening with my code:

```
~(storedist distance '(1 7) '((d (1 8)) (d (2 9))))
(1 (d (1 8))) (d (2 9)))
```

How can I fix this?

```
(define (store-dist dist coord data)
 (if (null? data) '()
  (if (null? (cdr data)) data
      (cons (dist coord (car (list (cadar data)))) 
        (store-dist dist coord (list (cdr data)))))))
```

Comment: In the example, what's the value of `distance`?

Comment: distance is just a function that finds the distance. So, its supposed to take what whatever that equals to and place it in the front of each sublist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part of the procedure is not right. For two coordinates, this doesn't even need to be a recursion (assuming all parameters are non-null):

```
(define (store-dist dist coord data)
  (list (list (dist coord (cadar data))
              (car data))
        (list (dist coord (cadadr data))
              (cadr data))))
```

For a more general approach (lists with more than two coordinates) use recursion:

```
(define (store-dist dist coord data)
  (if (null? data)
      '()
      (cons (list (dist coord (cadar data))
                  (car data))
            (store-dist dist coord (cdr data)))))
```

Comment: Ok, that works but what if I wanted to have more than two sublists? Right now, that works for two.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the simplest recursive approach to this type of problem; however, a lot depends on the `dist` code and your list structure:

```
(define (store-dist dist coord data)
  (if (null? data)
      '()
       (cons (dist coord (car data))
             (store-dist dist coord (cdr data)))))
```

In the above the `dist` function would need to unwrap/parse the `'(d (<x> <y>))` structure; otherwise use `cadr`.  Here is a candidate:

```
(define dist
  (let ((count 0))
    (lambda (c1 dthingy)
      (set! count (+ 1 count))
      `(,count (d (,dx ,dy))))))  ;; figure out dx, dy
```

Comment: That's not right, the output won't look like the expected output and probably will raise an error with OP's `dist` procedure

Comment: yeah it was only a guess; I figured the first numbers were just some count.  I figured that because `dist` for the second point should be `(sqrt 5)` which isn't 2 nor 2.0.  Cheers!